# Is it possible/a good idea to dispose of a thread in its catch and re instantiate itself in the finally block?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, exception

**Background:** I have multithreaded application that has one main UI thread and two threads that are super loops that run for the duration of the program. The worker threads basically read in some information and write an output to a Program Logic Controller.

I am running into an issue that I can't repeat when I'm debugging but only happens when the program is compiled and ran as an executable. I know the proper way of dealing with my issue is to find out why this is happening and deal with it. But while I am doing that I was wondering if it was possible to handle this issue in a different way...

**Quesiton :** 
My entire worker thread is in a

```
    Try
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
    End Try
```

Is it good practice / and even possible for me to dispose of my worker thread in the catch when it hits an exception and then restart / reinstantiate itself in the finally block?

I would Imagine a response to this might be "No thats not good practice because if you hit the exception mid loop, you will lose all the states of all your objects in your thread and if you restart it it might throw things out of sync."

This isn't actually going to be a problem for me, because all the states of all my objects are updated real time on the PLC, and the very first thing I do when I start my worker thread is read from the PLC to get all the states of all my objects.

The root of my question is, can a thread restart itself in the finally block?

Comment: Why not put a while(true) loop round the whole lot?

Comment: That is basically what this class is. The issue is when it hits an exception it bounces out of that while(true) loop, and I want it to restart itself without having to manually close the application and re start it.

Comment: just add another while(true) loop at outermost level - instant 'restart'.

Comment: If you enclose all of the code IN the loop in a try-catch then the code will not exit the loop unless an exception is thrown in the catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you changed your thread code from this

```
    Do While True
        'your code here
    Loop
```

to this

```
    Do While True
        Try
            'your code here
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Loop
```

then the thread can only exit if you have an Exit Do or an exception is thrown by the code in the catch block.

Answer (score 2):

It definitely isn't good practice, but it can be done.  However, you would want to restart it in the Catch block, not the Finally block.  The Finally block gets called at the end of the Catch, but it also gets called if the Try block finishes execution.

Answer (score 1):

To specifically answer your question; Is it possible? Yes - you can do something like this:

```
Public Sub Main
    'define thread object outside the Try block so we can use it 
    'again in the Catch block
    Dim thr as Thread
    Try
        thr = New Thread(AddressOf SuperLoop1)
        thr.Start
    Catch
        'you may want to log the exception so you know it has happened
         thr = New Thread(AddressOf SuperLoop1)
        thr.Start
    End Try
End Sub

Sub SuperLoop1
    'code for "super loop 1"
End Sub
```